# Value of $\Omega(0)$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

If we define $\Omega$ as the following, where $E_r$ is the energy in state $r$,
$$\Omega(E)=\int...\int d^{3N}p\ d^{3N}q\ \delta(E-E_r) \tag{1}$$
Then the laplace transform of $\Omega$ is the canonical partition function $Z(\beta)$,
$$L\{\Omega(E)\}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\Omega(E)e^{-\beta E}dE=Z(\beta) \tag{2}$$
Motivated by this idea, I was wondering what the following would work out to,
$$\beta \equiv \frac{1}{\Omega(E)}\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial E} \tag{3}$$
$$\beta \Omega(E) = \frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial E} \tag{4}$$
$$L\{\beta \Omega(E)\}=L\left \{\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial E}\right\} \tag {5}$$
$$\beta Z(\beta) = \beta Z(\beta) - \Omega(0)  \tag{6}$$
Which implies that,
$$\Omega(0) = 0 \tag{7}$$
This seems incorrect as the number of microstates associated with zero energy should be 1. Shouldn't it? Particularly for a microcanonical ensemble,
$$P_r=\frac{1}{\Omega} \tag{8}$$
And taking (7) and (8) into account it seems it would be *never* possible to have a system with zero energy. It seems like I'm doing some rather loose mixing and matching of ideas from the canonical and microcanonical ensemble. I think that's where I'm getting myself in trouble.

Comment: Where does $(3)$ come from ? In the Legendre transform $\beta$ is an independent variable.

Comment: It's the definition of $\beta$ in the microcanonical ensemble, and by extension, in general. Alternatively written as, $\beta = \partial \ln \Omega / \partial E$. And yes, that's true, but by that argument so is the average energy, yet we can write an equation for it that makes it dependent on other quantities, such as $P_r$.

Comment: Ok, but when you are computing the Laplace transform, you are switching to the canonical ensemble, where $\beta$ is a external parameter. You cannot use $(3)$ in the integral defining $Z(\beta)$

Comment: Is $\beta$ not an external parameter in the microcanonical ensemble? And yes, I do see that applying the Laplace transform inherently changes it to the canonical ensemble. But I would've thought that the definition in (3) holds in either case. Maybe this calculation is evidence that it does not.

Comment: Nevermind, I understand this now. In canonical ensembles ($NVT$), the temperature, and therefore $\beta$, is an external (independent) parameter, hence (2) is valid in that context. In the $NVE$ ensemble it isn't. That's a good enough answer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing equations from the microcanonical and canonical ensemble.

For clarity, let us write :
$$\beta_*(E) = \frac{\partial \ln \Omega}{\partial E}(E)$$
for the temperature in the microcanonical ensemble and $E_*(\beta)$ for the average energy in the canonical ensemble.

Then equation $(4)$ is rewritten :
$$\Omega(E) \beta(E) = \frac{\partial \ln \Omega}{\partial E}(E)$$
and because $\beta$ depends on $E$ you have :
$$\beta Z(\beta)\neq \int_0^{+\infty}\beta_*(E)\Omega(E)e^{-\beta E} \text d E$$